# JavaScript - for loop does not correctly allocate the x and y

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, path-finding

I'm using a [A* pathfinding script](http://www.briangrinstead.com/blog/astar-search-algorithm-in-javascript-updated) in a simple JavaScript 2D (canvas) game. I broke my game down to a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Anyway, my game is 15 columns across and 10 rows down.

**What is the problem?** Setting up the graph, I set up the `nodes` correctly (or so I think) using a simple `for` loop within a `for` loop to set up a 15 across and 10 down board.

So when I load up the page, I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '5' of undefined`

That is from this line `start = graph.nodes[12][5];` (from `SSCCE` below) where if you change the `5` (`Y`) then the number in the error will change.

Here is my `SSCCE`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='graphstar.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var board;
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='astar.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
{
        // UP to DOWN - 10 Tiles (Y)
        // LEFT to RIGHT - 15 Tiles (X)
        graph = new Graph([
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
        [1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1], 
        [1, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 13, 13, 1], 
        [1, 13, 1, 1, 13, 1, 1, 13, 1, 13, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 1], 
        [1, 13, 13, 1, 1, 1, 13, 13, 1, 13, 13, 1, 1, 1, 13, 1], 
        [1, 13, 13, 1, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 1], 
        [1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 1], 
        [1, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1, 1, 1, 1, 13, 13, 13, 1], 
        [1, 13, 1, 1, 1, 1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1], 
        [1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1], 
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
        ]);
        //Let's do an example test.
        start = graph.nodes[12][5]; // X: 12, Y: 5
        end = graph.nodes[2][4]; // X: 2, Y: 4
        result = astar.search(graph.nodes, start, end);
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
Loading... pathfinding. Look in Chrome Console/Firefox Firebug for more information.
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, my `grid` is `10` rows up and down and `16` columns across. However my `graph` doesn't interpret it that way.

See the whole `graphstar.js` here: http://pastebin.com/xUwghjRR (Here is `astar.js` for full package: http://pastebin.com/YMBtX66W)

This is where it's laid out in `graphstar.js`: **NEWLY UPDATED**

```
function Graph(grid) {
    var nodes = [];

var row, rowLength, len = grid.length;
for(var y = 0; y < len; ++y){
    row = grid[y];
    rowLength = row.length; // Expected: 16;
    nodes[y] = new Array(len);
    for (var x = 0; x == rowLength - 1; ++x){

            nodes[y][x] = new GraphNode(x, y, row[y]);

    }
}

    this.input = grid;
    this.nodes = nodes;
}
```

As you can see, the `for` loop is done by seeing how long the `grid`. `grid` length should output to `11` which is correct since we're looping the `Y` axis first. Then by `row` length which should output `16` which is correct since then we are doing the `X` axis.

So when I start the page I get this error:

So... I think I graphed it right however my `X` and `Y` still give undefined.

Comment: `row = grid[x]` ? Not `row = grid[y]` ?

Comment: That sadly did not make a difference. Still same error. :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your condition on the loop is false from the start so it never even enters the first loop, it should be

```
for(var y = 0; y < len; ++y){
```

also the call to `GraphNodes` probably sould be using `x` rather than `y`

edit:

there are also a few other little bugs in the code, the second loop need a capital L in `rowLength` and the order of the `x` and `y` in the posion you are saving the new node object to need to be switched `nodes[y][x] =`

edit2:

working function, beware I removed the function call to GraphNodes for ease of use, there is also a few console.log calls you will want to remove

```
function Graph(grid) {
    var nodes = [];

    var row, len = grid.length;
    console.log(len);
    for (var y = 0; y < len; ++y) {
        console.log(y);
        row = grid[y];
        console.log(row);
        var rowLength = row.length; // Expected: 16;
        nodes[y] = new Array(len);
        for (var x = 0; x < rowLength; ++x) {

            nodes[y][x] = row[x];
            console.log(nodes);

        }
    }

    this.input = grid;
    this.nodes = nodes;
}
```

edit 3:

the problem is probably because all your other code is looking at the co-ordinates as x,y where as the loops you have here and storing them y,x if you change the code like this it should let you keep all the other code using x,y

```
function Graph(grid) {
    var nodes = [];

    var row, len = grid.length;
    for (var y = 0; y < len; ++y) {
        row = grid[y];
        var rowLength = row.length; // Expected: 16;

        for (var x = 0; x < rowLength; ++x) {
        if(!nodes[x]){      
                nodes[x] = new Array(len);
        }
            nodes[x][y] = row[x];

        }
    }

    this.input = grid;
    this.nodes = nodes;
}
```

Comment: OK so I changed to what you said, you are right.. however I run it and I get this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined ` cause of this line: `rowLength = row.length;` so I saw I didn't specify  cause I had `row = grid[x];` and NOT `row = grid[y];` so I changed it and I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '5' of undefined `

Comment: the second for loop has the same problem as the first, I'll put the function I got working in the answer

Comment: Hm. So I did this and I had to switch the `start` and `end` node's `x`s and `y`'s and I do this `result.length` = `0`.

Comment: and I don't swap the `x` and `y` in those nodes... I get this `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '5' of undefined ` or whatever the `Y` is on the `start` node

Comment: Well, it works. But using my test example.. `console.log("Result length: " + result.length);` = `0`. Ah well. Thanks